# Etiam cursus semper leo vel facilisis. Sed imperdiet

Tags: audio-recording, volume, coronasdk

Etiam cursus semper leo vel facilisis. Sed imperdiet, nisi nec vulputate fringilla, neque nulla gravida risus, vitae scelerisque turpis augue ut felis. Integer ultrices auctor nunc id volutpat. Curabitur dapibus sagittis ante et ornare. Praesent dapibus consectetur massa, vel faucibus lectus rutrum vel. Maecenas imperdiet, massa vitae consequat tempus, odio velit gravida magna, ac porttitor odio elit sit amet dui. Nunc sem leo, pretium eu tempus vel, auctor eget enim. Sed bibendum ipsum eu sem ultricies sed fringilla mauris condimentum. Suspendisse in ipsum semper ante auctor consectetur eget fringilla elit. Nullam dictum faucibus enim.

Comment: Er! I think there is a syntax error here!
".ogg"`

Comment: No i mean SYNTAX ERROR!   there is a ' character after ".ogg"